# Get model table name without query

Tags: php, laravel

I have a package media library by spatie. I need to get table name of the model.

I know that I can do this:

```
public function getPath(Media $media) {
     $name = (new $media->model())->getTable()
}
```

But this creates a new query. I don't need to create an extra query on database. In table media, I have a column a `model_type`, where records can be like this: `App\ModelName`. Maybe I can get names of the model without a query?

Answer (score 2):

There is an answer in laravel framework github: 
https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1436 .
So it seems you will need to extend Media model. 
Example from github

```
class BaseModel extends Eloquent {

    public static function getTableName()
    {
        return with(new static)->getTable();
    }

}

class User extends BaseModel {

}


User::getTableName();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think "new model()" created a query on the database, it just spawns a new object instance of the model class. I don't know the library by heart, but given that it's a Spatie library, it probably functions very similar like Eloquent does, which has the same behaviour.